# Calling jQuery from Within Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am trying to create a timer to count up and then stop when the button is clicked. I got some code online from [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?68194-How-to-make-Javascript-count-up-timer) that I modified, but I am getting illegal invocation errors when I try to call the jQuery post method. I'm pretty sure it's a scope issue, but I'm not sure the best way around it. My modified code is below.

```js
var timer={

 init:function(id){
   this[id]={
   obj:document.getElementById(id)
  }
 },

 start:function(id){
    var obj=this[id];
    obj.srt=new Date();
    clearTimeout(obj.to);
    this.tick(id);
    $( "#climbTimer" ).unbind();
    $('#climbTimer').click(function(){timer.finalStop('climbTimer'); return false;});
    
    if ($('#'+id).html().indexOf('Start') != -1)
      $('#'+id).html('Stop Ascend<br><span id="elapsedTime">0.00</span>');
 },

 stop:function(id){
   clearTimeout(this[id].to);
 },
 
 finalStop:function(id){
  clearTimeout(this[id].to);
  
   $.post('php/climbTime.php', {team: document.getElementById('team').value, roundNum: document.getElementById('round').value, time: document.getElementById('elapsedTime')});
 },

 tick:function(id){
  this.stop(id);
  var obj=this[id],sec=(new Date()-obj.srt)/1000,min=Math.floor(sec/60),sec=sec%60;
  $('#elapsedTime').html(sec>9?sec:''+sec);
  obj.to=setTimeout(function(){ timer.tick(id); },100);
 }
 
 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error message you're getting?

Comment: Instead of `timer.finalStop('climbTimer')` you need to do `timer.finalStop(id);`. Better also not use deprecated `.unbind()`, but `.off('click')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- `document.getElementById('elapsedTime')` is passed as object property value to `$.post`: this is a DOM object, and jQuery will access all its properties trying to serialise it. That will lead to errors. Instead you should get the `textContent` property:

  ```
  $.post('php/climbTime.php', {
      team: document.getElementById('team').value, 
      roundNum: document.getElementById('round').value, 
      time: document.getElementById('elapsedTime').textContent // <---
  });
  ```
- You call `timer.finalStop('climbTimer')` but that is the name of your button, not the ID you used to start your timer with. You need to do:

  ```
  timer.finalStop(id);
  ```

I would also suggest to use `.off('click')` instead of `.unbind()` as the latter is deprecated since jQuery 1.7

Finally, you can better spot errors if you indent your code properly and avoid long one-liners. The `value` property was missing on the far right of a long line...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hadn't seen the missing value property, but that actually made me realize it wasn't the value I wanted, but the HTML contents since elapsedTime was a span.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I notice now it's a span generated in your code. NB: It is better to use `.textContent` than `.innerHTML` when you are dealing with text, otherwise you might get unwanted `&nbsp;`, `&amp;` and that kind of stuff.